# Add Safari Developer Library to Xcode

Tags: xcode, safari

Does anybody knows how to add Safari documentation to Xcode 4 (https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/), so I could use it offline.
I tried to look at adcdocset document
developer.apple.com/rss/adcdocsets.atom

Feed for Xcode 4.1. is
developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleXcode4_0.atom
For Lion Core Libraries
developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleLion.atom

So I tried to substitute Safari

```
developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.Safari.atom
developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.Safari5_0.atom 
developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.Safari5.atom
```

But with no luck.

Even tried to use the web url as feed url
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/

but nothing.

Is it even possible to get the Safari Docs to be viewable offline?
It would be normal to have it in Dashboard, but Dashboard hasn't got documentation browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I do think that since Extensions are build directly within Safari and no more in Xcode there is no way to have that documentation loaded in Xcode.
However you can download PDF version from the developer site.